# Создание файлов в FileTable по UNC-пути к каталогу используя C# (CLR SQL) - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, filestream, sqlclr

Есть тестовая процедурка, написанная на C# CLR SQL, которая потом работает как обычная хранимка. Процедура пытается создать файл в сетевой папке привязанной к таблице filetable в базе по соответствующему пути, но файл не создается, выдается ошибка "Такой запрос не поддерживается". FileTable вроде создавалась по всем правилам с доступами. Если создать файл по схожему пути в любой другой сетевой папке, не относящейся к filetable, то всё легко создается, если писать приложение, скажем WinForms или консольное, то в нужной папке тоже всё прекрасно создается, не создается именно в таком варианте хранимой процедуры. Не могу понять почему, в интернете конкретно такого случая найти не могу, но в документации сказано, что можно использовать средства ввода-вывода и создавать файлы прямо в папке по сетевому пути. Какие идеи по этому поводу, может кто сталкивался, уже замучил этот вопрос...

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void TestProcedure ()
{ 
    File.Create(@"\\PC-NAME\mssqlserver\FStreamData\FileTableName\1.bin");
}
```

Пробовались также варианты:

```
Stream stream = new FileStream(@"\\PC-
NAME\mssqlserver\FStreamData\FileTableName\1.bin", FileMode.Create, 
FileAccess.ReadWrite);
stream = new FileStream(@"\\PC-
NAME\mssqlserver\FStreamData\FileTableName\1.bin", FileMode.Open);
File.Open(@"\\PC-NAME\mssqlserver\FStreamData\FileTableName\1.bin", 
FileMode.Open);
```

- при попытках чтения существующих файлов выдается та же ошибка: Такой запрос не поддерживается. 
  В чем может быть проблема?

Скрипт импортирования сборки:

```
create assembly TPr from 'C:\Project1\Project1SQL\Procedures\CLR\bin\Debug\ClassLibra‌​ry.dll' 
with permission_set=unsafe
```

Нетранзакционный доступ включен.

Замечания: при использовании SQLFilestream с функцией GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() ошибка та же самая.
Приложение Блокнот не может открывать файлы содержащиеся в этой сетевой папке filetable, ЕСЛИ они содержат данные. Ошибка такая же: "Такой запрос не поддерживается", но это связано с тем, что filetable не поддерживает файлы отображенные на память, а Блокнот работает с такими. Честно, не знаю, относится ли это как-то к проблеме создания средствами IO из среды CLR.

Версия MS SQLServer2014

Файл должен создаваться в процессе выполнения процедуры, если записывать данные прямо в таблицу filetable, их размер будет ограничен, а использование костылей не приветствуется.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66425/discussion-on-question-by-layana----filetable--unc---).

Answer (score 1):

Проблему можно решить так: в UNC пути вместо имени компьютера указывается его IP-адрес, допустим, "\\192.168.0.104\mssqlserver\FStreamData\FileTableName\1.bin" но что делать, если надо именно имя - не знаю увы